# Unable to fix SMTP error in PHP mail sending

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

[image]

I am getting the above error when trying to send mail with smtp. Below shown is the error screenshot I got when tried printing the smtp settings with `var_dump($mail);` .Although it is mentioned as error in the screenshot , I didn't understand what is the actual error in it and to how to fix it. Any help to solve this is much appreciated.
[image]

The site I am testing is hosted in cpanel. I followed this link : `https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer` for the code used. I have installed `PHPMailer` with the composer command as mentioned in this link and then, just used the below code. Can someone tell me am I missing anything?

**Code**

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {

  $to = 'voicenetechnologies@gmail.com';
  $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
  $from = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
  $subject = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'subject', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
  $message = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'message', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

  $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
  $mail->isSMTP();                                     
  $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
  $mail->Username = 'vo******@gmail.com';               
  $mail->Password = 'vo******';                          
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                           
  $mail->Port = 587;

  $mail->addAddress($to, 'Voicene Technologies');
  $mail->setFrom($from, $name, 'Mailer');
  $mail->Subject = $subject;
  $mail->Body    = $message;

var_dump($mail);
die();
   
    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
  
} catch (\Exception $e) {
  echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

Comment: It looks like your hosting company is blocking access to the GMail servers. It's common practicve for hosting companies to require that you send email via their relay. This helps them defend against spammers. Contact your hosting company and ask them what arrangements they have for handling outbound mail.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular The site is hosted in cpanel. So, you meant to connect with cpanel support, right?

Comment: CPanel is server management software, not a hosting company. A hosting company is where the physical hardware of your server is located.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular But i also tried to send and receive mails with webmail account. even that has same error. I meant, not only the gmails have issue

Comment: There's little point in any further guessing here - contact your hoster's support, and ask them what's up.

Comment: It looks like a configuration issue since you have received SMTP 101 error. Also on another note i believe you are missing `$mail->IsHTML(true);`, but this isn't causing the issue. Also i would suggest you to use port `$mail->Port = 465;`. Did you follow the example given by PHPMailer https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps?

Comment: @Adi I already tried changing to `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';`  and  `$mail->Port = 465;` . It also gives the same error